# importing sqlite database from asset

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am beginner of android development with due search i was able to make a working sqlite database but i would like to import pre-made database from asset folder. though i have found tutorial and code for it but facing problem of integration in my code. can any one help me to provide coding help with this class:-

Wfdaadapter.java

```
public class Wfdaadapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FD1 = "fd1";
    public static final String KEY_FD2 = "fd2";
    public static final String KEY_FD3 = "fd3";
    public static final String KEY_FD4 = "fd4";
    public static final String KEY_FD5 = "fd5";

    private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "iigdatabase";
    private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "iigimport";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists "
            + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + KEY_FD1 + "," + KEY_FD2
            + "," + KEY_FD3 + "," + KEY_FD4 + "," + KEY_FD5 + ","
            + " UNIQUE (" + KEY_FD1 + "));";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Wfdaadapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public Wfdaadapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public long createCountry(String fd1, String fd2, String fd3,
            String fd4, String fd5) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_FD1, fd1);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FD2, fd2);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FD3, fd3);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FD4, fd4);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FD5, fd5);

        return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteAllCountries() {

        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null, null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;

    }

    public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
            mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_FD1, KEY_FD2, KEY_FD3, KEY_FD4, KEY_FD5 }, null,
                    null, null, null, null, null);

        } else {
            mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_FD1, KEY_FD2, KEY_FD3, KEY_FD4, KEY_FD5 },
                    KEY_FD1 + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, null, null,
                    null, null);
        }
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {

        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_FD1, KEY_FD2, KEY_FD3, KEY_FD4, KEY_FD5 }, null, null,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void insertSomeCountries() {


    }

}
```

method class for copying asset folder in app
Wfdahelper.java

```
public class Wfdahelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.monika.sharma12/databases/";

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "iigdatabase";

    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private final Context mCtx;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public Wfdahelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mCtx = context;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = mCtx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (mDb != null)
            mDb.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the
    // database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return mDb.query(....)" so it'd
    // be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

Comment: as such no errors are shown but how to access this database copying class and make it workable, where should i call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `createDataBase()` method inside constructor of `Wfdahelper` class

Example

```
public Wfdahelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.mCtx = context;
    createDataBase()
}
```

Comment: it ask for method upon inserting this.

Comment: didnot worked do i have to keep both class separate i think we need to merge it.

Comment: please help me i m struck on this

Comment: just copy your methods from Wfdaadapter into Wfdahelper. No need to keep `Wfdaadapter`  class.

Comment: i think i need to use createCountry(null, null, null, null, null); method after merging it??? am i right or wrong?/

Comment: Here is code [Wfdahelper.java](http://snipt.org/BFga0)  . Please make apropiate changes if required.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
     private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Alternative you can use :-

```
AssetDatabaseOpenHelper adb = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = adb.openDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM xxx;", null);
Log.d("MyApp", "cnt: "+c.getCount());
```